# ASP.NET and Fluent NHibernate Mapping help needed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to show a foreign key column 'NAME' field value in the Detail List (Manage page) page by using ASP.NET MVC and Fluent NHibernate.

FYI: Main Table is `Employee`. It has a foreign key (`DeptId`).
Please see below:

```html
//This is my Employee Class
public class Employee : Entity<int>
    {
        public virtual string EmpName { get; set; }
        public virtual int DeptId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Address { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        public virtual Boolean Status { get; set; }

        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    }
```

```html
//This is my Employee Map
public class EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
    {
        public EmployeeMap()
        {
            Table("Employee");
            Id(e => e.Id).Column("EmpId");
            Map(e => e.EmpName);
            Map(e => e.DeptId);
            Map(e => e.Address);
            Map(e => e.DOB);
            Map(e => e.Status);
        }
    }
```

```html
<!--This is the view-->

@foreach (var emp in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(e => emp.Id)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(e => emp.EmpName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(e => emp.Department.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(e => emp.Address)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(e => emp.DOB)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(e => emp.Status)</td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit","UpdateEmployee", new {empId = emp.Id}) | @Html.ActionLink("Delete","DeleteEmployee")</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

How can I display the department name?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not add `thanks` and other tag lines, they are discourage here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your Entity and your Map. You do not tell NHibernate about Reference beetween Employee and Department. 
You can remove `public virtual int DeptId { get; set; }` from Entity class and `Map(e => e.DeptId);` from EmployeeMap. Instead you must add References as in eddie_31003 post:

```
References(x => x.Department, "DeptId");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your EmployeMap you need to add a Reference to your foreign key. Not just a map.

```
References(x => x.Department)
    .TheColumnNameIs("ID")
    .PropertyRef(d => d.DeptId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a relationship between your two tables , you can access all the properties of Department by using: `emp.Department.XXX`
Not sure what's the name of your deptname attrbute

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(e => emp.Department.Deptname)</td>
```

Comment: I have already tried ur way <td>@Html.DisplayFor(e => emp.Department.Name)</td> but its not displaying.

Comment: Can you post your Department model?